# VB6 program stopped working on win7 after security update

Tags: windows-7, vb6

I have a customized VB6 text editor that I developed myself in VB6 (using the richtext control), developed on windows XP, but has always worked fine on windows 7 until this week after some kind of security update on my win7 laptop pushed out by my company.

Now running the program gives me the error:  "System error &H80004023 A Microsoft Software Installer error was encountered"

If I rerun the setup.exe (generated by the VB6 long ago), I get "run-time error 52 Bad file name or number"

Usually on a new Windows 7 system, it runs fine by just copying the .exe file onto the system.  But I know it relies on richtx32.ocx and mscomctl.ocx, but the complete installation program also installs standard VB6 dll's like MSVBVM60.DLL, OLEAUT32.DLL, OLEPRO32.DLLm MSVBVM60.DLL, COMCAT.DLL, RICHED32.DLL and VB6STKIT.DLL.

Any ideas on what I can try to get this working again?

Comment: After a very recent win10 update, I had some database software trigger an "office component installer" when I ran it (the first time after the update). This software is also a legacy VB application and does not integrate any Office applications (so presumably it is triggered by a control/library/ocx). I *suspect* this is similar to your installer error. One very common issue with older VB6 applications comes from progressively stricter "programs and files" and "user profile" permissions. I would start there.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this problem by copying mscomctl.ocx from \windows\system32 into \Windows\SysWOW64 and typing "regsvr32 mscomctl.ocx"